# Sample M.Content export profile for exporting a reference field

Tags: content-hub, content

I am looking to export M.Content items including column where I have used Reference fields. I can't figure out how M.Content relates the Reference field types.

My sample reference field (`Reference_Blog_Related`) appears twice in `M.Content` schema definition as below:

- Reference_Blog_Related M.Content is Parent of M.Content
- Reference_Blog_Related M.Content is Child of M.Content

Existing documentation doesn't cover this: https://doc.sitecore.com/ch/en/users/content-hub/manage-content--reference-use-case.html

Any help please?